# JHipster : Bower not found

Tags: bower, jhipster

when I `yo jhipster`, I have a

> Warning! bower is not found on your computer.

When I do a `bower -v`

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/esecly/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
```

You don't have access to this file.

when I do a `sudo bower -v`

```
1.7.9
```

So where's the problem ? Thanks you :)

Comment: what is the result of `sudo yo jhipster` ?

Comment: Tried too, the installation begin like without sudo, but there's still the Bower not found :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when bower was installed in your computer, is has the wrong authorization, so you can't run it, and for some reason, we can't run bower with sudo because of "too much authorization" (I don't find that very clever but well there must be some reasons).

So by doing chown, you actually took the precise file with the wrong authorization and change the username and the group name.

To have access to your own username and group name you use for your files, go to the repository and write :

ls -l

There will be all your files and the name of users and the name of groups in the **third** and **fourth** columns.

Then run : sudo chown -R Username:groupName path/of/your/file

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way, I will record it somewhere cause it looks like nobody had this problem before :

If you got the message `Warning! Bower is not found on your computer`

Try a `bower -v`

If permission denied, try a `sudo bower-v`

Then, if it answers your version, you must change rights.

For my case `Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/esecly/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'`

It is `sudo chown -R esecly:esecly /home/esecly/.config/configstore/`

Hope it will help someone :)

Comment: It works but you should rather consider installing nodeJS without requiring sudo. Google it and you'll find many solutions

Comment: I did. I tried all, I made my installation 5 times before it works. It's the only way I found for this error.